# Will my kitten remember me after a day of interaction?

Tags: cats, psychology

So I saved a stray kitten (a few weeks old, I'm not exactly sure) from being ran over by a car. I was looking for its mother, but I wasn't able to find her. It was getting late so I took her to my house and took care of her for a bit - and I have a feeling that it was probably a bad idea, but I really had no idea what to do. After a while, the kitten was getting attached to me - I think she thinks I'm her mom? - but unfortunately, I'm unable to keep the kitten until she is a few months old.

I have someone to take care of it until then. But would the kitten remember me after months? It sounds unlikely, but I would really like to know because I'm attached to her and it breaks my heart to be apart from her.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it's impossible to say for sure what a cat is thinking, but from personal observation, if you only interact with a kitten for a day, then are separated for months, the cat will most likely behave as if you are a stranger when you are reunited. I think it's often the case that kittens will seem more open to strangers and as the cat grows, it becomes more wary of them. On the positive side, you can still form a new bond that's just as strong with an older cat; it just might take a little longer.